# Conditional sentences without if type clause

Tags: clauses

Can sentences such as "I could have been a contender," be considered conditional on its own without an if type clause? Same thing with questions such as, "Should you have spoken to him that way?" Or is it not really a conditional sentence but a main conditional clause?

Comment: What do you mean by "a conditional sentence"? You mean something with both a protasis and an apodosis?

Comment: Well, that's considered the accepted definition of a complete conditional sentence, right? But what I'm asking is without the protasis is it still considered a conditional sentence? Since it's still an apodosis it can still stand on its own as an independent clause but would it still be considered a conditional sentence? And if not, what is it then?

Comment: A bare protasis, as in *”If you will let me”*, it not a sentence at all. A bare apodosis like *“Then I shall wash your windows”* is a complete sentence. Neither by itself is a conditional sentence and the lone protasis is not even a sentence at all.

Comment: 'Should you have spoken to him that way?'  uses _should_  deontically rather than epistemically. You require something like 'Should you have spoken to me that way, I'd have decked you.' Which doesn't provide you with a suitable example.

Comment: Okay. Apparently some need more details. First of all... @tchrist What? Of course a protasis isn't a sentence. That wasn't in question. I asked about 2 specific example sentences I wrote in the OP not the one you made up. I'm asking whether my example which doesn't have a protasis COULD be a conditional sentence such as is the case with the third conditional using "wish," as in, "I wish I would have spoken to seen him yesterday."

Comment: I sometimes see sentences expressing unreal conditions without a protasis, such as the one I gave in the OP or other would, could sentences. Ex: I would have been a great cop. I could have done better in school, etc.

Could they be still be considered conditional sentences?

Comment: Not by native speakers, no. And since you  mention "third conditional", a term unused by native speakers and linguists alike, I'm going to pass your question to our sister-site for learners, who will be able to answer your question in a way that makes sense to you, not in a way that makes sense to linguists.

Comment: There are some constructions like yours that don't have an _if_ clause that can be interpreted as conditionals, but they do require a noun phrase as subject: "The appointment of his nephew as finance minister would be a mistake", which can be glossed as "If his nephew is appointed finance minister, this will be a mistake". Is that what you are thinking of?

Answer (score -1):

The term "conditional sentence" is usually reserved for sentences that contain both a condition (a protasis) and a consequence (an apodosis), but the exact definition is unclear.

According to the [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-1):

> Although many conditional sentences use *if + will/would*, conditional sentences can also use other words instead of *‘if’* – e.g. *‘when’ ‘as soon as’ ‘in case’*.

**No clear definition**

An academic [paper](http://www.ling.cam.ac.uk/COPIL/papers/6-elder.pdf) by C. Elder also acknowledges that "when" sentences can at least in some cases be counted as conditional sentences, and notes:

> There is also no clear-cut class of conditional constructions

**Implied conditionals**

Some sources use the term "implied condition" to refer to a sentence that contains "would" with conditional meaning without a stated condition.  Some [resources](https://www.spring.edu/webroom/practice_g5_conditionals_5.html) describe such sentences as "implied conditionals", though I don't know if such terminology is widely accepted:

> I would apply for the job, but I don’t think I have a chance.

**Conditional verb forms**

Some grammars use the term "conditional" to refer to the use of *would* + infinitive, and "conditional perfect" for *would have* + past participle, particularly when used to express conditional meaning.

On the other hand, of course, the modal "would" does not always carry conditional meaning.  Sometimes it describes a habitual past action or a future in the past (such as a backshifted future in reported speech).

The modal "could" sometimes has conditional meaning (= "would have been able to"); other times it is used to express tentative potentiality (= "might be able to") or it can be used to discuss the past (= "had been able to" or "used to be able to"), etc.